# Keep quality after drawtext in ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg to put a subtitle in an avi video. I use this command to do it:

```
-i input.avi -vf drawtext="fontsize=80:fontfile=C\\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text=TEST_TEXT:y=h-line_h:x=(h+400)-(t*110)" output.avi
```

The output of ffmpeg console is :

```
>ffmpeg -i testwithout.avi -vf drawtext="fontsize=
80:fontfile=C\\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text=HELLO:y=h-line_h:x=(h+400)-(t*110)
" -an withsubtitle.avi
ffmpeg version N-62121-g634636e Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr  3 2014 23:30:16 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable
-zlib
  libavutil      52. 73.100 / 52. 73.100
  libavcodec     55. 56.107 / 55. 56.107
  libavformat    55. 36.101 / 55. 36.101
  libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavfilter     4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[avi @ 041307e0] non-interleaved AVI
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from 'C:\\Users\\╬Χ╧Β╬│╬▒╧Δ╬ψ╬╡╧Γ\\Desktop\\testwithout.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:07.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 147822 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 146812 k
b/s, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
, 1411 kb/s
File 'withsubtitle.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, avi, to 'withsubtitle.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf55.36.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 200
 kb/s, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> mpeg4)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  112 fps=0.0 q=20.0 size=     331kB time=00:00:03.93 bitrate= 689.8kbits/
frame=  222 fps=220 q=31.0 size=     479kB time=00:00:07.60 bitrate= 516.8kbits/
frame=  228 fps=210 q=28.7 Lsize=     485kB time=00:00:07.80 bitrate= 509.4kbits
/s
video:474kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing o
verhead: 2.350742%
```

But my input video is 135 MB and the output is only 613 KB. How i could keep the same quality of video?

Comment: Ok i edit it and i show you the console output. I understand that you telling me that my question is offtopic but i have seen a hundered of question included on stackoverflow so this is the reason that i ask my question here. Sorry about it!

Comment: Ok sorry again. :D !But could you help me to fix it or i must to delete my question from here and post it at Super User?

Comment: I am trying to open superuser but the host is down. :-/ so i will do it later. Until then can you help me to figure that error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filtering requires re-encoding, but there are several options to "keep the same quality", or at least provide a quality that is good enough.

## Lossless

To keep the same quality one option is to use a lossless format.

#### Example using the encoder huffyuv

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf drawtext -vcodec huffyuv -acodec copy output.mkv
```

#### Example using the encoder libx264

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf drawtext -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 0 \
-acodec copy output.mkv
```

A `-crf` value of 0 will initiate lossless mode for this encoder. See the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more info.

---

## Visually lossless

A second option is to use a visually lossless format. This is not technically lossless, but it will look lossless (or nearly so) and provide a much smaller file size. A `-crf` value of ~18 is generally considered to be visually lossless. Reduce the value if it does not provide an adequate quality. Again, see the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more info.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf drawtext -vcodec libx264 -crf 18 -acodec copy output.mkv
```

#### Chroma subsampling

You may need to adjust the chroma subsampling for the above example if you want it to play in non-FFmpeg based players because, depending on the input, `ffmpeg` will attempt to minimize or avoid chroma subsampling. However, note that this may cause color loss or artifacts.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf drawtext,format=yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -crf 18 \
-acodec copy output.mkv
```

The audio is simply [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) instead of re-encoded in these examples.

---

## Subtitles

A third option is to mux a subtitles stream into the video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -i subtitle.srt -map 0 -map 1 -codec copy output.mkv
```

This has the advantage of not touching the video and audio at all and any sane player worth using will allow you to turn the subtitles on or off during playback.

---

## Also see

- [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide)
- [The differences between Uncompressed, Fully Lossless, and Perceptively Lossless](https://superuser.com/a/347434/110524)

Comment: Can you provide an example for .ts when drawing text? If I do the conversion without text quality is great. If I add the text it gets very poor.

`ffmpeg -y -i video-audio.ts -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Roboto-Bold.ttf:text='test':fontcolor=white@0.95:fontsize=28:x=(w-tw)-10:y=(h-th)-10:shadowcolor=black:bordercolor=black:borderw=1" -codec:a copy video.ts`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/bfqQGc8L

Comment: @chovy 1. Your `ffmpeg` is old. Get a new one for macOS at [evermeet](http://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/). 2. You're outputting MPEG-2 video but using the not-so-good default settings. If that's the format you want then add `-q:v 2`. If you want H.264 instead remove `-q:v 2` and add `-c:v libx264`. If the H.264 is still too crappy add `-crf 18`.

Comment: @llogan ffmpeg -i input.asf -vf drawtext -vcodec libx264 -crf 18 -acodec copy output.asf output file size is larger than input file.

Comment: @theburningfire Makes sense. "Visually lossless" requires many bits. Increase your `-crf` value and/or use a slower `-preset`. See Encoding Guide link in answer for more info on those options. Also, it is not a fair comparison: `input.asf` was created from some other, cleaner source, but `output.asf` has to include all of the compression artifacts from the lossy encoder that created `input.asf`. These artifacts are not friendly to the encoder and the increased noise and entropy increases required bitrate (generation loss).